# Is my manager really on vacation or could this be related to being investigated?

Tags: management, human-resources

Note: I'm already seeking employment elsewhere, please no advice on that

Almost a month ago, my PM gave me a PIP and a final warning. No warning given prior. I kept extensive notes of conversations and events; combined with emails corroborating my documentation, I was able to give compelling evidence that my PM was attempting to put false, negative statements on my employee record, presumably to terminate me. I submitted this to our HR hotline.

HR initially said they wanted to focus on mediation between my boss and I, insisting they would turn the PIP into a first warning, nothing serious, you guys can get past this, you can get along again (and, in my still irritated opinion, glossing over the whole "I have detailed evidence that contradicts nearly every statement levied against me, while the PM in question keeps stating they were far too busy to write down/remember the details of the things they were accusing me of because unlike some people they have many things to do" part). They said they would be in touch in a week.

It's been four.

I've sent two emails asking for updates but no one has responded. Additionally I've noted that during this 4 week period, my boss, previously one who bragged about never taking PTO even in December, has all but disappeared - every time she's scheduled to be on-site, she's sick or her mom's sick or another contractor needs her that day.

Is it possible she's under investigation because I filed a complaint? I do not know how HR investigations work or whether an investigation would impact my boss's immediate ability to work but the radio silence from HR and the slow disappearance of PM is gives me a lot to wonder about.

Wish I had insight to what's going on up there

Comment: You have done your part by reporting with enough evidance to support, If there will be any changes then you migt be updated accordingly. If its not stopping your work you should focus on continue working and not worry about the outcome.

Comment: There is no way we can know what's going on with your boss and inside this company.

Comment: @nvoigt: you may not have anything useful to add to the discussion, but someone more familiar with typical patterns of behavior within HR departments may have some insight to offer based on the information given, or may have useful questions that can elicit enough information to be able to offer insight. The fact that you can't have specific knowledge of the details with the boss _does not mean that no one can recognize clues in information given or information that could be given_.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible she's under investigation because I filed a complaint?
>   I do not know how HR investigations work or whether an investigation
>   would impact my boss's immediate ability to work but the radio silence
>   from HR and the slow disappearance of PM is gives me a lot to wonder
>   about.

Obviously only HR can really tell you what is going on (and they most likely will not tell you, so it's probably better you don't even ask).

Generally speaking, yes, it is common for employees to be put on "temporary leave" if there are serious allegations against them. However, while details are usually kept confidential, there is usually an official statement that the person has been put on leave - colleagues do need to know about that. As you write that she is "sick or her mom's sick or another contractor needs her that day", it sounds more like your boss decided to stay away, possibly under a pretext.

Anyway, there is probably no point in overly worrying about that - you cannot really know what is happening, much less do something about it. It seems you have done what you could, now focus on finding good employment elsewhere.